# strange error with passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundler, passenger

A source file that the application requires, is missing.
It is possible that you didn't upload your application files correctly. Please check whether all your application files are uploaded.
A required library may not installed. Please install all libraries that this application requires.
Further information about the error may have been written to the application's log file. Please check it in order to analyse the problem.
Error message:
no such file to load -- bundler/setup
Exception class:
LoadError
Application root:
/srv/www/thecampusblitz.com/TheCampusBlitz/current
Backtrace:

## File    Line    Location

0   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `gem_original_require'
1   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in`require'
2   /srv/www/thecampusblitz.com/TheCampusBlitz/releases/20110326070845/config/boot.rb   6
3   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `gem_original_require'
4   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in`require'
5   /srv/www/thecampusblitz.com/TheCampusBlitz/releases/20110326070845/config/application.rb    1
6   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `gem_original_require'
7   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in`require'
8   /srv/www/thecampusblitz.com/TheCampusBlitz/releases/20110326070845/config/environment.rb    2
9   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `gem_original_require'
10  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in`require'
11  config.ru   3
12  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rack/builder.rb   46  in `instance_eval'
13  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rack/builder.rb   46  in`initialize'
14  config.ru   1   in `new'
15  config.ru

was working a week ago when i nuked my server any ideas?
bundler runs fine all gems installed.
rake runs fine,able to run migrations,console and database connectivity

Comment: One of the gems has an undocumented dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the key to your error: `no such file to load -- bundler/setup`  That suggests that Bundler is not installed on the server.

You say that bundler runs fine, not sure whether you mean that it runs from the console on the server - but it's not running for your passenger.  So perhaps your passenger settings are pointing to a different Ruby installation, and bundler is not setup for that.

I'd start there.

Comment: You should give some "upvote" and/or "accept" love to the answers that helped.  It's the StackOverflow way.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same error. Turns out it's a byproduct of using rvm. If you're using rvm, forgetting to set the gemset will result in this error. hth.

Comment: yep the next thing i looked was rvm which was problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed that one of the major problem was the file permissions on linux.
My user account didn't had enough privileges and passenger needs the app user account to have read/write privileges.
So permissions was the major problem apart from the other problems that these guys mentioned.
Those were present in my earlier installation.